# Can i identify in UML that method calls method from another class

Tags: uml, class-diagram, flowchart

I represented this chunk of code:

```
class Enemy{
    int _health;
    void Attack(){
        Player.GetDamage(25);
    }
}

class Player{
    int _health;
    public void GetDamage(int amount){
        _health -= amount;
    }
}
```

in UML like this:

[image]

Is it right representation?
I am new in UML and don't know if i'm doing things right.

Comment: Completely off-topic, but an operation with the name `GetDamage` is supposed to be a read-only get operation. Yours has a changes the health of the player. Think about choosing another name for the operations that clearly indicates that it will change something.

Comment: Thanks for remark. I will rename it to `TakeDamage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not correct. The association is wrong. This is only a dependency, which you need to show as dashed arrowed line. A class diagram only shows a static structure (i.e. how the classes relate to each other).

You show the dynamic part of calling in a sequence diagram:

[image]

The `Actor1` is some automata in the system which triggers the attack.

Comment: I forgot to mention. It's enemy's health. I edited code above.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, @Zaraza.132 what you have used so far is a class diagram, which is used to represent static information. It shows what classes you have, what are their attributes, operations and other features. But it is not used to show a dynamics of the system. To depict that you have to use other diagrams. One example (best for your case) is as Thomas has used in his answer. I recommend you read a bit more about UML and all available diagrams (especially those: Class diagram, Activity diagram, Sequence diagram, Use Case diagram, State Machine diagram and Components diagram)

Comment: Since you've edited a bit - you can also represent the actual value of properties on the sequence diagram. Now you'll have to replace `int` with `amount:int=25`. The rest of the answer as well as my previous comment remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! :)

Comment: " This is only a dependency, which you need to show as dashed arrowed line" : I feel like the question is very good because it helps a lot to understand an architecture if methods are linked with those lines in a class diagram. Unfortunately a lot of people discourage to do that and purpose sequence diagram instead (which doesn't give any context of what the class contains...)

Comment: @kingsjester Yes, dependencies (and more specific «trace») help a lot. Though primarily you want to show associations and dependencies only where you use other classes e.g. in parameter lists. Sometimes you start with dependencies and make them associtions later when you go to the details.